# Wordpress permalink structure change issue

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, permalinks

I have seen some other posts on SO about this issue, however none of the suggested solutions did work for me, so I repost.

After changing my permalink structure to `/%postname%/`, none of the links is working. I get the following 404:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /my-post-name/ was not found on this server.

Apache/2.2.20 (Ubuntu) Server at mysite.com Port 80
```

When I get back to the `default` permalink structure it starts to work again, but I want to have `/%postname%/` structure anyways.

My `.htaccess` file's `chmod` is 777.

After updating my permalink structure to `/%postname%/`, the `.htaccess` file generated by Wordpress is the following:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Any thoughts?

### Edit:

I tried to change permalink structure to the following:

```
/index.php/%postname%/
```

and it happily worked. However, the problem is now, not surprisingly, the links are in the following form:

```
www.mysite.com/index.php/my-page.com
```

My question is how can I remove `index.php` from my links. When I remove it from the permalink structure (i.e., `/%postname%/`), my links no longer work.

PS: Instead of using blog entries I use only pages in my site. If it is necessary my site is: mll.sehir.edu.tr.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like a problem with symlinks on your server.  Try this in your .htaccess and also please change it to 644 after making the change:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 12):

There are many ways how you can fix this issue, if you know the root of the issue.

#### Problem 1

Firstly, it may be a problem with your apache not having the mod_rewrite.c module installed or enabled.

For this reason, you would have to enable it as follows

Open up your console and type into it, this:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Restart your apache server.

```
service apache2 restart
```

#### Problem 2

You may also, in addition to the above, if it does not work, have to change the override rule from the apache conf file (either `apache2.conf`, `http.conf` , or `000-default` file).

Locate `Directory /var/www/`

Change the `Override None` to `Override All`

#### Problem 3

If you get an error stating rewrite module is not found, then probably your userdir module is not enabled. For this reason you need to enable it.

Type this into the console:

```
sudo a2enmod userdir
```

Then try enabling the rewrite module if still not enabled (as mentioned above).

To read further on this, you can visit this site: http://seventhsoulmountain.blogspot.com/2014/02/wordpress-permalink-ubuntu-problem-solutions.html

Comment: Amazing answer.  Very good that you are touching issues that are not completely related to the `.htaccess` file.  +1!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but i am using other url structure /%category%/%postname%/

The problems with de 404 error is because even if you set a certain structure, wordpress is always trying to create the urls with the word "category" on the url.

Try to type your urls like this: yoursite.com/category/postname, if you are not getting any error now is because we are close to resolving the error. Now try to install this wordpress plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/no-category-base-wpml/ to remove the "category" base from urls

Let me know about your progress

Comment: After setting Permalink structure to `/%category%/%postname%/`, links are still not working. I checked the `.htaccess` file. It is the same too. Should `.htaccess` change after I change the permalink structure?

Comment: Not i am using the default wordpress .htaccess. The same as you posted it. Did you tried to install the plugin that i told you?

Comment: Do you have installed apache mod_rewrite?

Comment: Yes, apache mod_rewrite is enabled. Since first part of your propose haven't succeeded, I didn't go on to the second part.

Answer (score 0):

Replace and try your .htaccess with this:

## Options +FollowSymlinks

## RewriteEngine On

## RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^hostname.com$

## RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.hostname.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue whenever i try to enable my site's permalink to mod_rewrite: "Pretty Permalinks". My site is one instance on AWS EC2.

```
404 Errors 

Page Not Found
The requested URL .... was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at mydomain.com Port 80
```

I tried all above methods, but not being fixed.

At last, I checked the /etc/apache2/sites-available/wordpress.conf, I found I used public IP address assigned to each instance by AWS. Once I change it to the current mydomain.com, it's working.

Sometimes, wordpress.conf would be locked by httpd (web serser), we need to stop and start it after edit. We also need to use: sudo service apache2 stop/start so as wordpress.conf could be reload again.

Hope my experience could help others.