# Internal Server Error apache

Tags: wordpress, apache

I work with wordpress, and I wanted to change my permalink from "default" to "post name". after i changed it i got an 404 error from apache. then I searched and get this: [Wordpress permalink structure change issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12951357/wordpress-permalink-structure-change-issue) when I write this commant "sudo a2enmod userdir" and refresh my page, I get 500 error:

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

here is my server log error:

> 127.0.0.1:45292] /var/www/tvvarzesh.dev/public_html/.htaccess: Invalid command 'BEGIN', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

what should I do? thanx

Comment: Can we see the contents of your **.htaccess** file, located in your web root directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow the below steps:

1. Go to `Dashboard` > `Settings` > `Permalinks`
2. Select a suitable permalink structure and click Save.
3. WordPress will generate a new `.htaccess` file code, copy the code.
4. Create a file named `.htaccess` in the WordPress root directory and paste the code into it and save.